# Distance from the set $A$ to the origin

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Let us define the subset $A$ of $\mathbb R^{2d}$ with $d>1$ by setting
>   $$
> A=\bigl\{\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}x_1 & y_1 & \ldots & x_d & y_d\end{array}\right)':x_i^2+y_i^2>c,\ i=1,\ldots,d\bigr\},
> $$
>   where $c$ is some positive constant. What is the distance from $0$ to the set $A$, i.e. $d(0,A)$?

By definition,$d(0,A)=\inf\{|x|:x\in A\}.$
We have that
$$
\sqrt{x_1^2+y_1^2+\ldots+x_d^2+y_d^2}>\sqrt{dc}.
$$
Hence, it seems that the distance should be equal to $\sqrt{dc}$. Is $d(0,A)=\sqrt{dc}$ correct?

However, I suspect that $A$ might be a complement of a closed ball with radius $\sqrt c$ and the centre at the origin. Then the distance should be $\sqrt c$, but I am not sure if this makes sense.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $d(0,A)=\sqrt{dc}$ is correct.

$A$ is not the complement of a closed ball with radius $\sqrt c$ !

Reason: from $x_1^2+y_1^2+\ldots+x_d^2+y_d^2 >c$ it does not follow, in general, that $x_i^2+y_i^2>c,\ $ for $i=1\ldots,d$